# Rails Best Practices for custom actions in Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am upgrading a quite older rails application to Rails4 which has quite a number of custom actions for a given controller.

My question is what is the best way to clean up these controllers without changing lot of view files ? I tried to cleanup by having only REST compatible actions but it is not possible with the time frame I am having to complete this task. Any clues would be appreciated.

For example in Following controller I would like to move filter_setup and somthing_else to a concern. Is this the correct way to do it ?

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
```

def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

def summary
    fiter_setup
  end

def fiter_setup
    somthing_else
  end

def somthing_else
  end
end

Answer (score 1):

I think a `concern` would be a better fit for shared methods, if this is the case go for it.

An approach you may take is to make private methods inside the controller class, let's say to refactor some instance variables (but use with care) and call them through a `before_action` callback.

Another good thing to do to reuse the views is to render that view on the action, let's say you have a list of products in the index action, but you have another bunch of actions to filter these products and they are displayed the same way, you can call the `render :index` method inside that action and the same template would be render, but be aware of the instance variables you are using as they should match or the view won't load the correctly.

Of course the best way to achieve this is to probably delegate all this logic into the model and keep your controller as lean as possible, you will be able to test it more easily.

My advise on this at the end of the day is to refactor as soon as you finish the migration, otherwise your happiness level for the project will decline very fast and you'll loose interest. Refactor may be hard at first but will definitely pay off.

My 2 cents.